# ng-file-upload unable to accept .apk pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to upload an apk file into file uploader. I am using https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload for file upload. Please expand snippet below to see the entire snippet.

```html
<input class="manage-apks-featured-images ion-plus-circled" placeholder="upload" type="file" name="apk" ngf-select="onChangePackageApk($files)" ng-model="newpackage.apk" ngf-pattern="'.apk'" ngf-accept="'.apk'" ngf-max-size="15MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile"
/>
```

The window that opens where I could browse the files from my system on clicking the above "choose file" button is not formatted/filtered by .apk files. How can I allow it to accept only apk files?

Answer (score 3):

Use `accept=".apk"` attribute.

```html
<input class="manage-apks-featured-images ion-plus-circled" placeholder="upload" type="file" name="apk" ngf-select="onChangePackageApk($files)" ng-model="newpackage.apk" accept=".apk" ngf-accept="'.apk'" ngf-max-size="15MB" required ngf-model-invalid="errorFile"
/>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I tried this earlier but it still does not work properly. It opens the window after multiple clicks or it takes like 15 to 30 seconds to open and its not consistent. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: At least in the snippet it opens immediately for me.

Comment: Also It works perfectly fine from localhost. The issue is only when I open this on server. The server opens file upload on all other file extensions but when I do accept=".apk" it doesn't work right.